# Auto-add today's date and time to new Entity title upon creation?

Tags: datetime, entities

I'd like to be able to auto-add today's date/time to the title of a particular Entity type when a new entity of that type is created. For instance, if I create an entity called "My New Entity", I'd like the title of that entity to actually be saved as "My Entity - 020513 - 103501" (assuming the entity is created on February 5, 2013, at 10:35:01 am).

Is this possible? If so, how can it be accomplished on a Drupal 7 website?

Thanks!

Comment: [`hook_entity_presave`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7) comes to my mind. But it's also fired before an Update op as well as an Insert. If you only need this for an insert, you probably need to figure out some way to distinguish if the entity in question is being updated or inserted as new. Maybe check the ID in the array, if it's an insert it will probably be empty (guessing here).

Answer (score 2):

**Option #1**

For Drupal 7 you're looking at the [Automatic Entity Label](http://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) module if you're after a particular entity.

> "Automatic Entity Label" is a small and efficient module that allows
>   hiding of entity label fields. To prevent empty labels it can be
>   configured to generate the label automatically by a given pattern.

**Possible option #2**

Another option is available if your Entity has actions exposed to [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules).  Simple create a rul that reacts on entity creation, and set some conditions as per usual.  Then, in the actions do the following:

1) Add an action for *Set data value*

2) Find your entity (node for example) and look for `:title` under data selector (e.g. `node:title`)

3) Click continue

4) On the next page, set the data value to be whatever you need with tokens (so your example *could* be something like as `[node:title] - [site:current-date]`)

Answer (score 0):

With [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) you can use **PhP** and node [tokens](http://drupal.org/project/token) to modify your node title.

If you need help for the php to use to render your title as My Entity - 020513 - 103501, don't hesitate to ask in a comment.